# How to edit file on console from Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to edit a file from CLI. I'm executing the `nano` command (I know that command will always be available); when I execute it, I can see nano's output but I cannot interact with it. How can I pass user input to the command? Do you have a better idea to easily edit a file from within my Java app?

This is my code:

```
String command = "nano /tmp/163377867.txt ";
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can [`nano` Command Manual](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/nano.html) help you?

Comment: I guess you would need to write a whole terminal emulator to do that.

Comment: Is it a console-based app or do you have some sort of GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with Java's `Runtime.exec` is that it connects stdin and stdout to "pipes," while many console programs need a TTY device.

One way to solve this problem is to make the Java program's [controlling terminal](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/runtime-exec-with-unix-console-programs/) available to the program you execute:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
                           "sh", "-c", command+" </dev/tty >/dev/tty"});
proc.waitFor(); // wait for user to finish editing the file
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's the solution.

Comment: I am running from gradle, I do not see the VI editor open up.