# Run external application until closed

Tags: java, console-application

I am writing a console application that is to make use of the system editor on *NIX. For that I have written a method which writes a string to a file, launches an editor to change that file, and then reads the file again. The problem is the call to run the editor doesn't wait for that application to have closed. I need the program to wait for the editor to have finished.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(editorcmd + " " + tmpfn);
```

The editor needs to access the console that the program is being ran within. It doesn't seem to do that either.

Comment: To add more info to @tianwei's comment, exec returns a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) object. Call the waitFor method on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", editorcmd + " " + tmpfn + " >/dev/tty </dev/tty"}).waitFor();
```

This will pause the current thread until the process has finished, with stdin and stdout piped to the controlling terminal.

Comment: Using this it exits immediately, I assume because the editor doesn't have access to the console.

Comment: OK, I'm fixing it with info from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340788/how-to-edit-file-on-console-from-java

Comment: Sorry, forgot a closing brace.